# File sizes are being reported differently when opening images from camera roll and sharing

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an app that takes a picture and saves it to the camera roll and a view that shows images saved in my library.

I've implemented a share option.  When I open an image from my library (taken from the camera roll) and I send it via email using the share option it says that the image is 10Mb.

If send the same image from the camera roll it says the is 1.2Mb. When I open both images on my laptop, the file sizes are different.

Does anybody know why is it happening? Is there anything I am missing in order to reduce the file size to send from my app?

Here is the code of the sharing functionality:

```
- (IBAction)share:(id)sender {

    NSArray *activityItems = @[self.imageView.image];

    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];

    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact ];

    [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: This question involves pre-release APIs so should only be discussed on Apple's own developer forums in the relevant area.

Answer (score 0):

Image that exists in your library is original, and has biggest size.

It's up to you to resize it to make it smaller.